# how to display form when hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a collage of pictures.  I want to be able to hover over them and click on "make profile picture" so make it a profile picture.

Similar to facebook where if you hover over a picture, there are options to edit / like / comment.

Thanks.

I have the following, but it's not working.

```
<%= link_to image..., :id => "pic" %>
<%= link_to "Profile Pic".... , :remote => true, :id => "pf" %>
```

Jquery

```
$('#pic').hover(function() {
  $('#pf').show()
})
```

Comment: What does `it's not working` mean?

Comment: @ExplosionPills: Perhaps it's lazy? Maybe it needs the proper motivation.

Comment: Perhaps the disrepancy between `link_to` (first line; an underscore) and `link to` (second line; a space) is the cause here?

Comment: @ExplosionPills, nothing happens when I hover over the picture.

Comment: @ming do you get an error?  Did you wrap your code in document.ready or put it in right before `</body>`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills, no errors.  The link appears next to the picture though.

Comment: `The link appears next to the picture though` so does that mean your problem is solved? The link appearing when you hover over the picture is exactly what you wanted right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/jrb9249/UsnfT/3/

The inline code looks like this:

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="div_parent">
    <img id="myImg" src="http://s13.postimage.org/x23kf7ycz/DSC02036.jpg"
    onMouseOver="javascript:myMouseOver()"/>
    <div id="div_child"
    onMouseOut="javascript:myMouseOut()">
        <a target="_blank" id="myLink">Make profile Picture</a>
        <br><br>
        <a target="_blank" id="closeLink" onclick="javascript:mytest()">Close</a>        
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
function myMouseOver(){
    $('#div_child').fadeIn('fast');
};

function mytest(){
    $('#div_child').fadeOut('fast');
};
```

CSS:

```
div
{
    border:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#div_child a:hover
{
    cursor:pointer;
}

#div_parent
{
    position:relative;
}

#div_child
{
    position:absolute;
    left:155px;
    top:0px;
    display:none;
    border:solid 1px gray;
    padding:5px;
}

#div_parent img
{
    width:150;
    height:112;
}

#closeLink
{
    color:blue;
    font-size:6;
    float:right;
}

#closeLink:hover
{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

It uses the relatively positioned parent and absolutely positioned child to offset the options box. Then using simple mouseover and onclick functions via jquery the user can easily view and close the box.

I originally attempted to use a onMouseOut function to close the popup, but I'm not quite sure how to make that work properly. The close link solves the issue though.